# Maze Solver ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a Maze Solver, but I encounted an *ArrayOutOfBoundsException* on this line:

```
wasHere[row][col] = false;
```

I don't see how there could possibly be such error, since the width and height (number of rows and columns) as represented in the `maze`, `wasHere`, and `correctPath` are all the same. All arrays show **7 columns** and **4 rows**.

```
private static int[][] maze = {{2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
        {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}}; // The maze
private static boolean[][] wasHere = new boolean[7][4];
private static boolean[][] correctPath = new boolean[7][4]; // Solution

for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
{
    // Sets boolean arrays to false
    for (int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++)
    {
        wasHere[row][col] = false;
        correctPath[row][col] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of row and col when this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `wasHere` to be 7 by 4, whereas `maze` is 4 by 7.  You will get an error when you try to access, for example, `row = 0`, `col = 4`.